# Java Assignment Solution Request: Consecutive Equal Numbers

Tags: java, arrays, loops, input, numbers

This java assignment is frying my brain and I was hoping someone could solve this for me and explain how they found the answer? I have been trying for hours to comprehend it :/ this stinks!

Assignment: Consecutive Equal Numbers

Problem Description:

Write the following function that tests whether a two-dimensional list has four consecutive numbers of the same value, either horizontally, vertically, or diagonally.

```
public static boolean isConsecutiveFour(int[][] values)
```

Write a test program that prompts the user to enter the number of rows and columns of a two-dimensional list and then the values in the list. The program will display
Found four consecutive occurrences of n.
if the list contains four consecutive numbers with the same value n. Otherwise, it will display
Did not find four consecutive occurrences.

I pretty much tried to understand arrays but there is so much terminology and numbers and it destroyed my mind :/

Comment: I understand your desperation. The beginning of programming can be very frightening. Nevertheless, people on Stackoverflow won't appreciate if you just give an assignment and ask them to solve it for you. Could you write more about what questions you have, what approaches you tried, where did you get stuck...? I also recommend you to google more about the things you didn't understand. The Internet is full of resources for beginners.

Comment: Great question.  These can be confusing if you don't frequent the topic, when coding.  You'll need to utilize _for-loops_ and conditional checks.

Comment: I found several answers online, but was struggling with how arrays work. There also wasn't a Sample Run given in my assignment for some reason, and that definitely threw me off. But thankfully a solution was given and I will try to learn and work from it! :)

Comment: Here is the Java tutorial on arrays.  _[Arrays (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tested on basic 5 x 5 inputs, and works.

It's just *for-loops* and conditional checks.
Let me know if you have any questions—I added comments above each test.

```java
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ui();
    }

    static int rows, columns;

    static void ui() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("enter rows and columns:  ");
        rows = scanner.nextInt();
        columns = scanner.nextInt();
        int[][] values = new int[rows][columns];
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            System.out.printf("enter row %d:  ", row + 1);
            for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++)
                values[row][column] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("isConsecutiveFour(values) = " + isConsecutiveFour(values));
    }

    public static boolean isConsecutiveFour(int[][] values) {
        /* check horizontal */
        int previous, count;
        for (int[] row : values) {
            previous = row[0];
            count = 0;
            for (int index = 1; index < row.length; index++) {
                if (previous == row[index]) count++;
                if (count == 3) return true;
                previous = row[index];
            }
        }
        /* check vertical */
        for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
            previous = values[0][column];
            count = 0;
            for (int row = 1; row < rows; row++) {
                if (previous == values[row][column]) count++;
                if (count == 3) return true;
                previous = values[row][column];
            }
        }
        /* check horizontal, left to right */
        for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
            previous = values[0][column];
            count = 0;
            for (int row = 1; row < rows; row++) {
                if (column + 1 >= columns) break;
                if (previous == values[row][++column]) count++;
                if (count == 3) return true;
                previous = values[row][column];
            }
        }
        /* check horizontal, right to left */
        for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
            previous = values[rows - 1][column];
            count = 0;
            if (rows - 2 < 0) return false;
            for (int row = rows - 2; row >= 0; row--) {
                if (column + 1 >= columns) break;
                if (previous == values[row][++column]) count++;
                if (count == 3) return true;
                previous = values[row][column];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Example input and outputs.

These should pass.

```
enter rows and columns:  5 5
enter row 1:  0 1 2 3 4
enter row 2:  4 0 1 2 3
enter row 3:  3 4 0 1 2
enter row 4:  2 3 4 0 1
enter row 5:  1 2 3 4 0
isConsecutiveFour(values) = true
```

```
enter rows and columns:  5 5
enter row 1:  1 2 3 4 5
enter row 2:  1 2 3 4 5
enter row 3:  0 0 0 0 0
enter row 4:  1 2 3 4 5
enter row 5:  1 2 3 4 5
isConsecutiveFour(values) = true
```

```
enter rows and columns:  5 5
enter row 1:  1 2 0 3 4
enter row 2:  1 2 0 3 4
enter row 3:  2 1 0 4 3
enter row 4:  1 2 0 3 4
enter row 5:  1 2 0 3 4
isConsecutiveFour(values) = true
```

And, these should fail.

```
enter rows and columns:  5 5 
enter row 1:  1 2 3 4 5
enter row 2:  5 4 3 2 1
enter row 3:  0 1 0 1 0
enter row 4:  5 4 3 2 1
enter row 5:  1 2 3 4 5
isConsecutiveFour(values) = false
```

```
enter rows and columns:  3 3
enter row 1:  1 1 1
enter row 2:  1 1 1
enter row 3:  1 1 1
isConsecutiveFour(values) = false
```

Test case

```
enter rows and columns:  6 7
enter row 1:  0 1 0 3 1 6 1
enter row 2:  0 1 6 8 6 0 1
enter row 3:  5 6 2 1 8 2 9
enter row 4:  6 5 6 1 1 9 1
enter row 5:  1 3 6 1 4 0 7
enter row 6:  3 3 3 3 4 0 7
isConsecutiveFour(values) = true
```

Comment: I appreciate the help! I currently have the brain of a caveman, but I will do my best to learn what this code is doing and work from it! Also THANK YOU for a Sample Run, my assignment never had one and I couldn't picture what was going on

Comment: Sure, no problem.  Java has a tutorial available _[here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)_, and also the _[JavaDoc documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/module-summary.html)_ is always resourceful.

Comment: Oh oops I had another question, how do I make a 6 x 7 input?  When I entered the row and columns in that amount I got the wrong answer with numbers in my assignment? I was using the first box in this link https://media.cheggcdn.com/media/50c/50c9c2f5-aac5-4ec4-9eb8-5d87033cdbf8/php7s7WuA    and got false for some reason?

Comment: I'm unable to get that link to work.  Can you post the input data?

Comment: enter rows and columns:  6 7
enter row 1:  0 1 0 3 1 6 1
enter row 2:  0 1 6 8 6 0 1
enter row 3:  5 6 2 1 8 2 9
enter row 4:  6 5 6 1 1 9 1
enter row 5:  1 3 6 1 4 0 7
enter row 6:  3 3 3 3 4 0 7                    When I entered these numbers, I got false

Comment: Got it, I figured out the error.  So, it should be checking for _count == 3_ and not _4_.  Essentially, the first match is 2 values, thus would only need 2 more increments to be a valid 4.  Thanks for the update, I would have complete overlooked it.